# add a class to anchor tag in current menu item in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
                $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

             if ($item->menu_order == 1){
             $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="active" ', $item_output, 1);
            }
                return $item_output;
            }
            add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

The code above puts an  `<a class="active">` to the first menu item.
I want to put this class only to current menu item (the selected menu).

any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, does the `.current-menu-item` class not work for you?

Comment: why dont you just simply add class to `<li>` instead of anchor or you can also use ? `.current-menu-item` class in css for `active`

Comment: thanks for the comments.. I just added to #myMenu li.current-menu-item a and manage to get it working...
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can achieve this using wp_nav_menu_objects filter.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_objects($objects, $args) {
    foreach($objects as $key => $item) {
        $objects[$key]->classes[] = 'my-class';
    }
    return $objects;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);
```

The only problem is that these classes will be added to li elements and not to links directly. But it's default WordPress behavior and I don't think you should change it.

If you really have to change it, it is still possible:

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    // you can put your if statements in here (use item, depth and args in conditions)
    if ( $depth == 1 ) {
        $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="level-1-menu" ', $item_output, 1);
    } else if ( $depth == 2 )
        $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="level-2-menu" ', $item_output, 1);
    }
    // .. and so on
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Check it [enter link description here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108092/adding-different-classes-to-anchor-in-navigation-menu)

Comment: this does nothing to isolate the `current` page anchor and does not answer the question

Comment: sorry for that i change my answer check it @ charlietfl

Comment: @bhavesh tried your solution and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: This is good to insert a class to the anchor (as opposed to the list item). The problem, for me, is, it replaces any existing classes - effectively, my "active" class. So it removes the ability to style for the active menu item.